OS kills process before it executes stop script
I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.10 (Ootpa).
I create a init script to stop MQSeries.
before it runs the script from /etc/init.d, the MQ processes are killed.
LOG extract:
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: Stopped target RPC Port Mapper. 
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2519 (amqzxma0) with signal SIGTERM. 
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2567 (amqzfuma) with signal SIGTERM. 
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2575 (amqzmgr0) with signal SIGTERM

PROOF that the script runs:
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 mqseries[6715]: Stopping Queue-Managers:
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 mqseries[7012]: Waiting for queue manager 'AWPIIBMQ101' to end.
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 MQSeries[2519]: FFST record created in /var/mqm/errors/AMQ2519.0.FDC
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Succeeded.
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: Stopped Session c2 of user mqm.
Jul 10 11:45:45 awdiopace101 mqseries[7012]: IBM MQ queue manager 'AWPIIBMQ101' ended.


Did you check dmesg or journalctl to check for OOMKiller ?

I did , there is nothing in dmesg for OOMKiller

Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: Stopped target RPC Port Mapper.
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2519 (amqzxma0) with signal SIGTERM.
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2567 (amqzfuma) with signal SIGTERM.
Jul 10 11:45:44 awdiopace101 systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 2575 (amqzmgr0) with signal SIGTERM.

Add that to the question. Do not post it in the comments where it can get lost is is more difficult to parse.

There is nothing in the systemctl that kills any processes. The stop script won't run from systemctl if you have a SUDO in the script. now it all works fine
